# Removing Edit Permalink/View "Custom Post Type" areas

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

Trying to replicate some functionality I've seen on a few other themes before, but would like to know/understand for my own uses.

I've created a custom post type, called "testimonials". I believe I've knocked out a pretty good chunk of the setup, using [Justin Tadlock's awesome post on Custom Post Types](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress). I've also seen his post on removing meta boxes, which is great. The thing I'm after is, when you usually type in a title on a post/page and click off of it, you'll get an "edit permalink" area. Normally, this is actually a useful thing, but in my case, for "testimonials" or "slideshow slides" this may actually confuse the user. Furthermore, once you save a "testimonial" or "slide", you may not want there to be an actual "single view". I'm not sure how it is normally done (poked around inside WooThemes -- but I'm still lost). I could do this with CSS, but looking at the actual source code of the page for Woothemes for example... it's just gone (which is what I prefer). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a filter `get_sample_permalink_html` that returns this area as a string. Here's how you can use it:

```
<?php
    add_filter('get_sample_permalink_html', 'perm', '',4);

    function perm($return, $id, $new_title, $new_slug){
        global $post;
        if($post->post_type == 'testimonials')
        {
            $ret2 = preg_replace('/<span id="edit-slug-buttons">.*<\/span>|<span id=\'view-post-btn\'>.*<\/span>/i', '', $return);
        }

        return $ret2;
    }
?>
```

**Updated** the code. Please check this.

**Updated** Changed the double quotes to single quote on view-post-btn. Tested up till 3.2

Comment: Wow! That was quick :) I really appreciate the sample code. I implemented it and see it outputting what is normally returned "off-click" in the permalink area -- do you have an example where I would actually remove this area just for testimonials, like you had with the "if" statement? Really starting to understand the power of filters, but am a little fuzzy on the PHP for this area. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I could've completed the entire code, but you need a regular expression to remove the `<span>` that surrounds those 2 buttons from the `$return` variable, and I'm not good at regex! In place of `testimonials` from the if part in the code, you can put any post type to check.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm unfortunately a little fuzzy on that subject as well - I may have to give the CSS way a try for now - unless someone else chimes in. Thank you again very much!

Comment: You're welcome... keep checking this thread, I'll look around for someone to write the regex and update my answer.

Comment: Hi... Please check the code now.

Comment: AMAZING! Works perfectly! I can't thank you enough - I'm definitely going to read up more on the power of functions (and yes, REGEX too) :)

Really appreciate the continued help on that. Thanks again!

Comment: Congrats and You're welcome! Yes, REGEX is awesome, but a little tricky to learn! Read about the documented WP filters first in the codex. Once you're comfortable with them, then you can start digging deeper in the core files for more expert stuff!

Comment: Hi @Rutwick - funny enough, for some reason the code snippet above is actually effecting all post types, not just 'testimonials' Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try a `print_r($post)` to check the post type. I think it might be a simple typo from my side.

Comment: Hi @Rutwick - As always, appreciate the quick responses. For some reason, doesn't seem to be working, I might not have that part right, but I've even tried http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type grabbing the post type after global $post -- and assigning it to a variable before running the if statement. Any suggestions welcome - thank you very much!

Comment: Did the print_r return the right post type to you?

Comment: Hi @Rutwick - yes, I saw this in the output:

[post_type] => testimonials

Comment: That's strange... as far as the code goes, this should work right. Let me try something else and get back with the code... Keep checking here...

Comment: Thanks @Rutwick really appreciate it. Just to confirm, I've been placing that entire code snippet in my functions.php file (just to make sure I'm not making some newbie mistake there) :)

Comment: Perfect man... `functions.php` is a perfect place for this code!

Comment: Hey @Rutwick sorry - wanted to confirm you were still looking at this :) Got a little confused by your last response. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - had to remove the check on this - still unresolved - thanks for all the continued support though.

Comment: That's fine man! I checked this code on a couple of environments with custom post types and it worked all right. I don't understand why it doesn't work for you!

Comment: Hi @Rutwick - if you've checked it and it works - then I'll need to figure this one (as it could very well be that it's something on my side). I'll mark this one as accepted - thank you for your time!

Comment: No problem @Zach! You can leave the answer as unaccepted until it works for you. I checked it on my current live projects which has 2 cpts, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use CSS to hide it, based on your client's role. If you're interested, I can give you a code sample.

Comment: Really appreciate you taking a look. I think I had done that previously, here is how I went about doing it:

    `add_action('admin_head', 'testimonials_admin_css');
        function testimonials_admin_css() {
            $tempDir = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
            global $post_type; if (($_GET['post_type'] == 'testimonials')) :    
                echo "<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" . $tempDir . "/inc/css/admin_testimonials.css' />";
            endif;
    }`

I think the PHP way may be cleaner though.

Comment: @Johnathan Wold: Would be more useful to post the code sample as it might interest other people at StackExchange as well... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If using css:

```
#edit-slug-box {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: The OP explicitly said that he was looking for a solution that didn't involve CSS.