# Disable title link in the backend for non-admins

Tags: links, title

I need to make posts not editable by non-admins in the backend, is there a way to disable the link in the title of the posts when they view the list of post published?
Thanks!

Comment: Modify capabilities using a plugin such as Members.

Comment: This project is meant to be the standard for al my upcoming websites and I'd rather prefer to continue to add new functions to functions.php instead of installing plugins (with the risk that any new update coul compromise the site or having conflicts with another...).
Up to now I've been able to add all my edit through functions.php and this is the reason for seeing if it's possible to have a sort of code...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the links below achieve what you're looking to do when they're combined. If you want to have administrators or just specific admin IDs excluded you could add to the if statement in the function like I have done with `current_user_can` function;

```
function perm($return, $id, $new_title, $new_slug){
    global $post;
    if($post->post_type == 'testimonials' && current_user_can('manage_options'))
    {
        $ret2 = preg_replace('/<span id="edit-slug-buttons">.*<\/span>|<span id=\'view-post-btn\'>.*<\/span>/i', '', $return);
    }

    return $ret2;
}
if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
    add_filter('get_sample_permalink_html', 'perm', '',4);
}
```

I have not tested this.

[Removing Edit Permalink/View "Custom Post Type" areas](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31627/removing-edit-permalink-view-custom-post-type-areas)

[How to check if a WordPress user is an “administrator”](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2006/03/27/how-to-check-if-a-wordpress-user-is-an-administrator/)

Comment: Haven't tested, but there's an error: change both occurrences of `$ret2` to `$return`. **If the condition is not met**, you are returning a null variable.